# Optimising stored procedure for better performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, query-optimization, relational-database

I am using a SP which takes around a minute to execute; any ideas for optimisation? For indexing I am using is the `accessCodeID`, amount of data is around 20k,

```
 SELECT COUNT(tbAC.abGUID) AS total,
       tbAC.abGUID,
       tbAC.aVID,
       tb_tt.used,

FROM   tbAC
       INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(abGUID) AS used,
                          abGUID
                   FROM   tbAC AS tbAC_1
                   WHERE  ( batchGUID = @id )
                          AND ( aVID > 0 )
                          AND ( isVoided = 0 )
                          AND ( isCodeUsed = 1 )
                   GROUP  BY abGUID) AS tb_tt
         ON tbAC.abGUID = tb_tt.abGUID
       INNER JOIN tbV
         ON tbAC.aVID = tbV.vendorID
WHERE  ( tbAC.aVID > 0 )
       AND ( tbAC.batchGUID = @id )
       AND ( tbAC.isVoided = 0 )
       AND ( lowLevelNotified = 0 )
GROUP  BY tbAC.abGUID,
          tbAC.aVID,
          tb_tt.used,
          tbV.name,
          tbV.firstName,
          tbV.lastName,
          tbV.tel,
          tbV.email,
          tbV.contactName
```

[image]

Comment: You will have to provide far more information, such as : tables schema information, existing indexes you have, data quantities and preferably a query plan.

Comment: Please edit your post with the information, opposed to adding the information in comments :)

Comment: -1. Vote to close. If you think we are reading your mind and are uanble to provide the nededed infroamtion to make sense out of that - try working at McDonalds. At least post your hardware pecs and the query execution plan and the table definitions.

Comment: I don't understand the hostility here, Mr A. While we can't tell you how to exactly fix this query, we can certainly give you suggestions about how to go about researching and fixing it.

Comment: i was asking for suggestions not the answer , as my query works but its just the time which it takes to execute so i was looking for any suggestions where i can improve the performance of d query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming allocatedVendorID is functionally dependant on abGUID, try:

```
SELECT sum(case when lowLevelNotified = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS total,
       tbAccessCode.abGUID,
       tbAccessCode.allocatedVendorID,
       sum(case when isCodeUsed = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS used,
       tbV.name,
       tbV.firstName,
       tbV.lastName,
       tbV.tel,
       tbV.email,
       tbV.contactName
FROM   tbAccessCode
       INNER JOIN tbV
         ON tbAccessCode.allocatedVendorID = tbV.vendorID
WHERE  ( tbAccessCode.allocatedVendorID > 0 )
       AND ( tbAccessCode.batchGUID = 'abc-def' )
       AND ( tbAccessCode.isVoided = 0 )
GROUP  BY tbAccessCode.abGUID,
          tbAccessCode.allocatedVendorID,
          tbV.name,
          tbV.firstName,
          tbV.lastName,
          tbV.tel,
          tbV.email,
          tbV.contactName
```

Comment: total and used columns displays same results

Comment: That's strange - you can see that the logic is different. How does it compare with the results from the old query? What numbers are returned if you add a count(*) column? Can you add some sample data to the question?

Comment: i tried with count but no difference , the used one shows the right amount , but i guess there is an issue with total as it is showing the same numbers as used

Comment: How does it compare with the output from the original query?

Comment: it returns 36 rows while the original one returns 32 rows , the extra 4 rows are the one which have total = 0 , which is not in original query, added image in the question

Comment: sorry i wrote wrongly , just interchange the text with original one to new one

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that I suggest you try.

Examine the **execution plan** in Management Studio.
That will show you where the most time and resources are consumed. Then, you will know where, for example, you may need to add an index to a table.

I would examine the two queries separately. Start with the nested query. Optimize it by itself. Then, try to do the outer query without the inner one. Then, put them together.

If you're a fan of videos, you might get some help from [this short one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P97_oFfD218), and the other ones referenced there.

Once you know you're looking for "execution plan", you can Google plenty of stuff -- and find lots of good questions here in SO. Here are [two](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Examining_Query_Execution_Plans) [articles](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) I found for starters.